How to get BAS report via API using existing functionality
BAS report is available in GUI of Xero, however it appears it is not available in API.  Is there a way to generate it from other sources, e.g. pull all the relevant transactions from API and put together a BAS report in a local database using PowerBI for example or other reporting tool?
Thanks.
I looked through Xero documentation and emailed Xero API support team.  I got an answer that BAS report is not currently available via API.
